# How to notify users once a specific time is reached (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a table in SQL Server, with each record storing the specific time at which users must be notified. What is the best way to make push notification once that time is reached using ASP.NET Core?

I wrote a component that queries database for each incoming `HttpRequest`, but I thought this was not wise approach.

Comment: There are really only two basic approaches. The first is to poll the server at set intervals for updates. In that case, you likely want to cache your query results for the duration of your query interval so you're not requerying the database for every client request. The second is to maintain a client/server connection using e.g. SignalR (which uses WebSockets). That way, you can do the polling on the server, and send out notifications to all clients that remain connected. That tends to take more server resources, but is often faster.

Comment: Thank yo dude @Jeremy Caney